# listening for checkbox change

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have the following code, which does not work. It is supposed to add the `.selected` class to the ancestor `<li>` any time the checkbox state is changed (checked / unchecked). But nothing happens.  No errors, but no adding/removing of the class either.

JavaScript (list-control.js)

```
(function() {

    $('[data-list-control]').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
        $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('selected');
        console.log('change event fired');
    });

})();
```

HTML

```
<body>
...    
<ul data-list-control>
        <li>
            <div class="list-control_left">
                <input type="checkbox" id="Item30" tabindex="402">
                <label for="Item30"></label>
            </div><!-- .list-control_left -->
            <div class="list-control_main">
                <div class="list-control_title">
                    <span class="icon-incoming-calls left medium">&nbsp;</span>
                    Caller Name
                </div>
                <div class="list-control_subtitle">The Subject Line</div>
            </div><!-- .list-control_main -->
            <div class="list-control_right">
                <div class="list-control_right-top">

                </div>
                <div class="list-control_right-bottom">
                    00:00 p
                </div>
            </div><!-- .list-control_main -->
        </li>
    </ul>

...


    <script src="js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/widgets/off-canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="js/widgets/drop-list.js"></script>
    <script src="js/widgets/list-control.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Show your HTML. Have you tried `.is(':checked')`

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/B5z24/. BTW, you could compress the contents of your function to one line:     `$(this).closest('li').toggleClass('selected');`

Comment: What is the `.selected` class doing to the checkbox?

Comment: That is strange that it works on jsfiddle but not locally for me. I am using some trickery to show a fancy looking checkbox.  When I click on the label, the checkbox is checked. But for some reason it does not seem to fire a change event.

Comment: Is this the exact code you are using or do you insert the checkbox via js at some point? Sorry to ask, but have you wrapped your js code in  a `document.ready` callback?

Comment: @marionebl I wrapped it in (function() { ... code ... })();  That is the exact code.  No post loading.

Comment: Try `$(function () { ... });` as wrapper. http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/B5z24/1/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/B5z24/2/. Note the setting `No wrap - in <head>` under `Frameworks & Extensions` in the left sidebar.

Comment: I just discovered that the last of the <ul data-list-control> elements works fine.  I have three of these lists.  Why would only the last one work?

Comment: That kind of behavior would happen when you duplicate IDs, but you're using classes. And in my fiddle if you duplicate the list multiple times it still works fine.

Comment: @marionebl  removing the closing () made it completely unresponsive.

Comment: Could you update your question with the exact wrapper you are using? Is this script defined in the head or in the body?

Comment: Tried removing your other scripts? What's in drop-list.js?

Comment: @marionebl I updated the code like you suggested.  I also triple checked for any duplicate ids on any of the inputs just in case that was messing something up. Everything looks fine, but just wont work for me.

Comment: @j08691 I removed the other two js files.  No change in behavior.  Still only adds/removes `.selected` to the last of the three lists.

Comment: When I changed the selector to `$('.w_list-control')` instead of `$('[data-list-control]')` all three lists started to work correctly.  Then I realized I had put the brackets around the data attribute in the HTML.  Stupid me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had typed brackets around the attribute in the html in two of my three lists.  This: `<ul [data-list-control]>`  rather than this:`<ul data-list-control>`.  Just a dumb typo :(

Comment: Just a note, if you had shared the code you were using, instead of just a piece of it, odds are at least one person here would've spotted that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that

```
(function() {
    $('[data-list-control]').change(...);
})();
```

Runs before `domready`.

Try replacing it with either

```
$(function() { ... });
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... })
```

jsfiddles illustrating the issue:

- Working, with `domReady` callback: http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/B5z24/1/
- Failing: http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/B5z24/2/

Comment: Never mind, this does not apply as the scripts are embedded at the end of the `<body>`. Just noticed in your updated answer. No `domReady` callback needed.